# C# Entity Framework code First Relación muchos a muchos

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc, code-first

Tengo un código en C# Entity Framework code First.

Por un lado tengo `Article` y por otro `Tax`. Un un Articulo puede tener muchos Tax y un Tax puede estar en muchos Artículos. Muestro lo que estoy haciendo y el error que me da:

```
public class Tax
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Nombre")]
    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The {0} field can not have more than {1} characters.")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The field {0} is mandatory.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Article> Articles { get; set; }
}


public class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Nombre")]
    [MaxLength(200, ErrorMessage = "The {0} field can not have more than {1} characters.")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The field {0} is mandatory.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ArticleType ArticleType { get; set; }
    public ArticleSubType  ArticleSubType { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Tax> Taxes { get; set; }
}
```

Al hacer la migración me da el siguiente error:

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation
>   property 'Article.Taxes' of type 'ICollection'. Either manually
>   configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the
>   '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in
>   'OnModelCreating'.

Me pueden ayudar por favor 
Muchas gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En principio debes crear una tabla auxiliar (Code First) que **relacione** los **Articulos** (`Article`) con los **Taxs** (`Tax`), eso es precisamente los que te está indicando el error.

La tabla sería por ejemplo **`ArticleTax`**, y relacionaría las dos tablas que ya tienes por su clave primaria:

```
public class ArticleTax
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order=1)]
    public int IdArticulo { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order=2)]
    public int IdTax { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public Article Article { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Id")]       
    public Tax Tax { get; set; }
}
```

Una vez vez que realices la Migración, las tablas `Article` y `Tax` quedarán relacionadas mediante la nueva tabla `ArticleTax`.

---

**ACLARACIÓN**: Posiblemente debas **cambiar** las **claves primarias** de las tablas `Article` y `Tax`, para que EF entienda correctamente la relación. Sería así:

```
public class Tax
{
    [Key]
    public int IdTax { get; set; }
    ...
    ...
}


public class Article
{
    [Key]
    public int IdArticle { get; set; }
    ...
    ...
}
```

Y la nueva tabla `ArticleTax`, quedaría así:

```
public class ArticleTax
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order=1)]
    public int IdArticle { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order=2)]
    public int IdTax { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("IdArticle")]
    public Article Article { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("IdTax")]       
    public Tax Tax { get; set; }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**: En el caso de obtener el error:

> Entity type 'ArticleTax' has composite primary key defined with data annotations. To set
>   composite primary key, use fluent API.

Puedes utilizar el **Fluent API** para crear la **doble clave primaria** de la tabla `ArticleTax`.

En tu `DbContext`, en el método `OnModelCreating()`, crea la clave compuesta de esta manera:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ArticleTax>()
        .HasKey(c => new { c.IdArticle, c.IdTax });
}
```

**NOTA:** Por supuesto elimina los atributos `[Key][Column(Order=1)]` y `[Key][Column(Order=2)]` de la tabla `ArticleTax`.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda pero mira el mensaje al migrar.Entity type 'ArticleTax' has composite primary key defined with data annotations. To set composite primary key, use fluent API.

Comment: @MarceloPírez:; Ok, he editado la respuesta. Revísala por favor.

Comment: Excelente, quedó impecable y solucionado, muchas, muchas gracias

Comment: [Column(Order=1)] y [Column(Order=2)] se usan para crear una llave compuesta? tambien no olvidar llamar base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); dentro de OnModelCreating :P

Comment: @BrianJerezBaez: Para crear una clave compuesta se utiliza `[Key]`, `[Column(Order=x)]` solo indica el orden en que se creará cada clave en la tabla de la BD.

Comment: es necesario modificar el registro con FluentAPI si uso column(order)?

Comment: @BrianJerezBaez. Tu que crees?. Me gustaría saber tu opinión.

Answer (score 0):

Alternativamente puedes crear una relación de muchos a muchos de la siguiente manera

`Entidad de rompimiento:`

```
public class MiTablaDeRompimiento
{
    public int TipoAId { get; set; }
    public TipoA TipoA { get; set; }

    public int TipoBId { get; set; }
    public TipoB TipoB { get; set; }
}
```

`Agregar una lista en las entidades a relacionar`

```
public class TipoA
{
    public List<TipoB> MisTiposB { get; set;}
}
```

.

```
public class TipoB
{
    public List<TipoA> MisTiposA { get; set;}
}
```

`DbContext: (Sobre escribir OnModelCreating)`

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<MiTablaDeRompimiento>()
        .HasKey(c => new { c.TipoAId, c.TipoAId });
}
```